# How to scrape a table and convert it into CSV with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'd like to gather some lecturer info and export it into CSV. I read some article and tutorial using `python`. The code looks like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = "https://uin-suka.ac.id/id/page/detil_dosen/197606110000002301"

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
print(df)
```

and the output look like this

```
                             0  1                                   2
0                         Nama  :     Dr. Nina Mariani Noor, SS., MA.
1                Program Studi  :   Interdisciplinary Islamic Studies
2                     Fakultas  :                        Pascasarjana
3       Jenis Pegawai | Status  :  Pegawai Tetap BLU | Aktif Mengajar
4  Jabatan Akademik | Golongan  :                      Lektor | III/C
5                        Email  :                                   -
6          Pendidikan Terakhir  :                                  S3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

the csv table I created look like this

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tih7.png)

The problem is, how can I pull the second column and put it into CSV as row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using `pandas` try to use [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) and [`pandas.transpose()` / `.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) to get your goal without `selenium` overhead:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_html('https://uin-suka.ac.id/id/page/detil_dosen/197606110000002301')[0]\
    .set_index(0)\
    .T.drop(1)\
    .to_csv('myfile.csv', index=False)
```

| Nama | Program Studi | Fakultas | Jenis Pegawai | Status | Jabatan Akademik | Golongan | Email | Pendidikan Terakhir |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dr. Nina Mariani Noor, SS., MA. | Interdisciplinary Islamic Studies | Pascasarjana | Pegawai Tetap BLU | Aktif Mengajar | Lektor | III/C | - | S3 |

Comment: i got an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File PycharmProjects\DataDosen\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0]\
  pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 317, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  pandas\io\html.py", line 1205, in read_html
    return _parse(
  pandas\io\html.py", line 982, in _parse
    parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)
  pandas\io\html.py", line 939, in _parser_dispatch
    raise ImportError("lxml not found, please install it")
ImportError: lxml not found, please install it
Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Just follow the recommendation installing lxml~ pip install lxml You can also try running it with pd.read_html(url, flavor='html5lib') instead.

Answer (score 2):

without using df and assuming input is dict

```py
keys = res.keys()
with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(res)
```

using df I think you need to transpose it first.

```py
df = df.drop('1',axis=1)
df = df.set_index('col1').T
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Comment: got an error while using df:
Traceback (most recent call last):
PycharmProjects\DataDosen\main.py", line 12, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
\PycharmProjects\DataDosen\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 248, in __init__
    raise FeatureNotFound(
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Process finished with exit code 1